# Funny Border around button css

Tags: css, input, submit, border

Please take a look:

http://dageniusmarketer.com/NicheResearch/

I am trying to remove the odd border around the big orange button, along with the tiny text that says submit. The line of code for the button is:

```
<input name="submit" class="WatchNow_Button" type="image" value="Submit" />
```

The class has no border element.

Been playing with this code for a good hour with no luck.

How do i remove the text and the border and leave just the orange button only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the border because you're not providing an image to render for the <input>. Either convert it to a type="submit" or give it a src attribute.